# How to build dependent modules in maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have current maven multi-module project structure :

```
./pom.xml 
project1/service-a/pom.xml
project1/service-b/pom.xml
project2/service-x/pom.xml
```

I need to build  service-b and  service-a when building service-x . I defined dependencies in service-x/pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.com/groupId>
         <artifactId>service-a</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.com</groupId>
         <artifactId>service-b</artifactId>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

But when I’m building service-x , service-a and service-b are not building.

I tried  running following commands from parent module folder:

```
mvn package -pl project2/service-x
mvn package -pl project2/service-x -amd
```

And from  service-x folder:

```
mvn package
```

There is no error messages. It's only builds service-x

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
mvn package -pl project2/service-x -am
```

instead? I guess you mixed up the flags `am` and `amd`.

Answer (score 0):

Your service-x is in project 2 and your service-a and service-b is in project 1. When you build project 2 you cannot build project 1 at the same time using maven package. But you can write a scheduler to build all the projects at the same time or create pipeline build using jenkins.